# Unity Capture And Display Live Camera Feed

Tags: unity, android, ios

I want to display the video using the device camera on specific part of the screen on iOS, android and Editor. I was able to find the WebCamTexture which display the camera video on the Quad (3D Object). Now I want to record the video and save it on the disk. Is there are way to do that ? Or is there a better way to do that using unity or through plugin ?

Answer (score 0):

There are some assets available for this. With the free one you have to do it little technically, the second one in this list is straight forward I guess. Check them out.

1. **Free solution:** https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/16005 (EveryPlay). This records the screen so what you can do is record your screen while making the video, then save this.
2. **Paid Solution:** Also there is a paid plugin out there in Unity asset store that records and save recorded video https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19682